# how to take array items and make corresponding spans in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

im making a hangman game and i was able to get the user to input a word and i was able to change that into an array. Now i cant seem to take those array values and make them appear as separate spans.

```
var makeAlphabetArr;
var $wordInput = $(wordInput);
var x;
var p = $('#wordInputArr');
var button = $('button');
var startGame = $('startGame');

button.click(function(){
  if (startGame){
console.log('it works');
```

set a variable to the wordInput

```
userWord = $wordInput.val();
makeAlphabetArr();
spanValues();
}
});
```

function to take userWord and split into array

```
function makeAlphabetArr(){
 x = userWord;
```

takes the user input and splits it into array value

```
 x = x.split('');
  console.log(x);
  p.val(x).hide();
}
```

Comment: You would need to loop through the array and create a new element for every value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bb67vpxu/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `each` method to loop through the array:

```
function makeAlphabetArr(){
    x = userWord;
    x = x.split('');
    console.log(x);
    $(x).each(function() {
        p.append($('<span>').html(this));
        console.log(this);
    });
}
```

Inside the loop, `this` will be a letter of the user input word.

[jquery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)